# How to properly use clCreateProgramWithIL() with a spir-v binary kernel?

Tags: clang, opencl, llvm-clang, spir-v

I need to create an OpenCL application that instruments the code of the OpenCL kernel that it receives as input, for some exotic profiling purposes (haven't found what I need, so I need/want to do it myself).

I want to compile the kernel to an intermediate representation (LLVM-IR right now), instrument it (using the LLVM C++ bindings), transpile the instrumented code to SPIR-V and then create a kernel in the hostcode with `clCreateProgramWithIL()`.

For now, I am just compiling a simple OpenCL kernel that adds 2 vectors, without instrumentation:

```
__kernel void vadd(
    __global float* a,
    __global float* b,
    __global float* c,
    const unsigned int count)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    if(i < count) c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

For compiling the above to LLVM IR, I use the following command:

```
clang -c -emit-llvm -include libclc/generic/include/clc/clc.h -I libclc/generic/include/ vadd.cl -o vadd.bc -emit-llvm -O0 -x cl
```

Afterwards, I transpile `vadd.bc` to `vadd.spv` with the `llvm-spirv` tool ([here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-LLVM-Translator)).

Finally, I try building a kernel from the C hostcode like this:

```
...
cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithIL(context, binary_data->data, binary_data->size, &err);
err = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
...
```

After running the hostcode, I receive the above error from the `clBuildProgram` command:

```
CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
error: undefined reference to `get_global_id()'
error: backend compiler failed build.
```

It seems that the `vadd.spv` file is not link with the OpenCL kernel library. Any idea how to achieve this?